# Running asynchronous shell commands inside a synchronous one, i.e. wait for result

Tags: shell, asynchronous

I'd like to run commands asynchronously, but to be able to get the prompt back, only when all commands are finished

For example

I'd like to run something like this
sleep 1 & sleep 7 & sleep 3 & sleep 4

and have the shell released after 7 seconds

For instance, I'll use this with multiple curls for downloading simultaneously, and get the prompt back when everything would be downloaded

Answer (score 3):

The conventional approach is to collect the PIDs and wait on them in turn; this means you know the exit status of your commands and whether any of them failed.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^^- important: the below uses bash/ksh extensions not available in /bin/sh

pids=( )
sleep 1 & pids+=( $! )
sleep 6 & pids+=( $! )
sleep 3 & pids+=( $! )
sleep 4 & pids+=( $! )

num_failures=0
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
  wait "$pid" || (( ++num_failures ))
done

if (( num_failures > 0 )); then
  echo "Warning: $num_failures background processes (out of ${#pids[@]} total) failed" >&2
fi
```

---

If you need compatibility with `/bin/sh`, then this changes a bit:

```
#!/bin/sh
pids=''
sleep 1 & pids="$pids $!"
sleep 6 & pids="$pids $!"
sleep 3 & pids="$pids $!"
sleep 4 & pids="$pids $!"

num_failures=0
for pid in $pids; do
  wait "$pid" || num_failures=$(( num_failures + 1 ))
done

if [ "$num_failures" -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "Warning: $num_failures background processes failed" >&2
fi
```

---

...or, if it's sufficient to wait for all background jobs without detailed status of which one(s) failed:

```
sleep 1 & sleep 6 & sleep 3 & sleep 4 &
wait
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that unless you have background jobs you don't want to wait on, you can simply call `wait` with no arguments without having to store all the process IDs of the background jobs.

Answer (score -1):

Ok found out

wrapping them inside $( ) does the trick

for instance

time $(sleep 1 & sleep 7 & sleep 3 & sleep 4) gives back the prompt indeed after 7 seconds

Comment: Just because it works doesn't mean it's a good idea. You're reading the stdout from these `sleep` commands and running that combined stdout as a command; surely that's not a desired side effect.

Comment: (try changing your first `sleep 1 &` to `{ echo touch /tmp/i-can-run-arbitrary-code; sleep 1; } &`, then look in `/tmp` -- and you'll see that there's actually potential for security impact, if any program can remotely control the stdout of things you run in the background this way).